# Oracle TO_DATE not keeping format

Tags: oracle

Since this seems more of a syntax question, my search didn't produce any useful results.

I'm attempting to make a query that gets European data from an American database using GMT time. I need to get the European time, but can't seem to get it working correctly.

Lets say "myDateField" = '01-01-2010'

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(myDateField + (60 / 1440), 'Mon" "DD", "YYYY')
```

Produces exactly what I want, but I need it to stay as a date.
Produces: '**Jan 01, 2010**'

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(myDateField + (60 / 1440)), 'Mon" "DD", "YYYY')
```

Merits a "Not a valid Month" error.
Produces: **Error**

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(myDateField + (60 / 1440), 'Mon" "DD", "YYYY'), 'Mon" "DD", "YYYY')
```

Works, but the formatting is lost.
Produces: '**01-01-2010**'

How can I format this so that I can get the result the first statement gives, but also keep it as a date? Or is there a better method altogether?

**EDIT:**
Just as an example of this particular query working under a different circumstance... This is the same query, but instead of converting to European time, it converts to another timezone in North America.

```
SELECT TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(NEW_TIME(myDateField, 'GMT', 'MDT')), 'Mon" "DD", "YYYY')
```

Produces exactly what I want, while keeping the data as a date.
Produces: '**Jan 01, 2010**'

**In summary:**

Is there any way to take "myDateField + (60 / 1440)", or use the "FROM_TZ" Keyword, and make the result use the 'Mon" "DD", "YYYY' format, while retaining it's Date type?

Comment: comment on your "In summary": No - that is, your client may choose some way of formatting DATETIME values, just like Dan pointed out. But that is just the local way of the tool to represent the date. It does not change the actual data value. Using TO_CHAR does change the value - it serializes the date to a string in the specified format. You could reparse the string and interpret it as DATE, but the result will again be a date value with no inherent formatting. The format is simply not part of the data type or the values it governs.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'm just living in the clouds...
Just for a quick question, why does TO_DATE(myDateField + (60 / 1440), 'Mon" "DD", "YYYY') produce a "Not a valid Month" error? (You seem to be quite informative on the subject)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New answer, since the first one adressed the confusion over date vs char, not timezones.

You asked if there is a better way. I think there is: use oracle time zone support.

see: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch4datetime.htm#i1006333

Example query to convert a datetime to another timezone:

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(
         CAST(TO_DATE('1999-12-01 11:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP)
       , 'America/New_York'
       )
       AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles' "West Coast Time"
FROM DUAL;
```

Using these functions ensure that the math is correct. After that you can of course format it the way you want to, for example:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(
         FROM_TZ(
           CAST(TO_DATE('1999-12-01 11:00:00','YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') AS TIMESTAMP)
         , 'America/New_York'
         )
         AT TIME ZONE 'America/Los_Angeles' 
       , 'MON DD, YYYY') "West Coast Time"
FROM DUAL;
```

...but like I pointed out in the first answer, the result here will be a CHAR, not a date.

Comment: The funny part is, I was playing around with that prior to posting. It doesn't allow me to format it the way I had hoped. Sorry to sound picky.

Comment: I added a summary to my question, if that helps any.

Comment: I added an example of formatting this the way you specified. The reason why I would advise you to use the FROM_TZ and AT TIME ZONE constructs is that they ensure the math is done right. Time zone calculation is not trivial, and you should use the built in facility if it's there. The formatting is a matter of presentation. You would only reformat to display or export the date - not if you want to insert it in the database.

Comment: Thanks. This is about as close as I'm going to get, so I'll give this a try. Just means the users have to do their own work. Heh...

Answer (score 4):

I think it is important to realize that the formatting you desire takes effect as part of converting from `DATE` to `CHAR` types. So your requirement, "setting the format but keeping it as date" does not make sense - not in Oracle it don't.

If you just want to add some time interval to a date, and keep it a date, this is all that is needed:

```
myDateCol + (60 / 1440) -- add one hour to the date
```

and if you want to format that in european style, it becomes

```
TO_CHAR(myDateCol + (60 / 1440), 'MON DD, YYYY')
```

but of course, it will then be string, a human readable representation of the actual date value. And because of the format, this actually lacks the time informatioin.

You can of course convert that back toa date:

```
TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(myDateCol + (60 / 1440), 'MON DD, YYYY'), 'MON DD, YYYY')
```

but seriously - there is no point - because the time part is not present in the string, this date will actually have 00:00:00 as time. So you just lost information.

This becomes clear when you do things like this:

```
TO_CHAR(myDateCol + (60 / 1440), 'MON DD, YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

compare that too:

```
TO_CHAR(
  TO_DATE(
    TO_CHAR(myDateCol + (60 / 1440), 'MON DD, YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
  , 'MON DD, YYYY'
  )
, 'MON DD, YYYY HH24:MI:SS'
)
```

(the last exprression demonstrates how you truncated the time fiels)

Comment: Thanks for the advice... In this particular instance, time isn't required. Thank you for the insight though, and I will update the question with a query I have that does work correctly under a similar instance, with the only exception being that it uses "NEW_TIME" instead of the (60/1440) expression.

Answer (score 3):

A date is just a date - it doesn't have an intrinsic string format. What it does have is a default format, that is, when you query a date into some program or library that extracts it as a string, there is a default setting as to how it will be formatted.

One approach is to simply query the date and have your client program format it. For example, in Java you can use the DateFormat class.

But you can also try `ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'Mon dd, yyyy'`

and that might work.

Edit: Your second query returned a `not a valid month` error for me. Did you run that after following my `ALTER SESSION` suggestion?

Comment: The query string is being used inside another program (SAP Business Objects)... By formatting the date in the query string, it means that users don't need to format it every time they use it.

Comment: Then return a CHAR value, not a DATE.

Comment: That's how I currently have it. The problem is that they can't use much of the functionality that is provided when using dates. That's why I need to go back and change it to a date, but can't figure out how to get it correctly.

Comment: Then this becomes SAP's problem. If SAP is treating the value as a date, it's SAP's job to figure out how to display it, not Oracle's.

Comment: Very true... The only thing with that is that I'm doing this so the users don't have to on every report they make, and universe designer don't have to change every date field.